# Get 48x48 icon size of any file, folder or drive in java

Tags: java

How to get 48x48 icon size of any file, folder or drive in java?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by getting an icon of a folder or drive

Comment: Maybe he wants to generate some preview icon from their contents?

Answer (score 1):

SWT has this functionality. Look at the "Program" class. I don't think standard java can achive this without JNI or another native layer.